# Why are the dynamic content options limited when initializing a variable

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft-flow, power-automate

I would like to make a variable in a workflow to specific content in a column I call Parent List ID. However, when I try, the only dynamic content options I get are for the item ID. Why do I only get that one option? Do I have to use an expression to get the information from the right column? I tried using the item function, but that doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your ParentID column on that list set up as a number type field?

I set mine up as a number type field with zero decimal places, and you can see that it *is* available in the dynamic content selection box:

[image: screenshot of flow with custom column available in dynamic content]

I'm fairly sure what's happening is that when you specify the type of the variable, SharePoint/Flow is filtering out the available choices in the dynamic content to only ones of that same type, so you don't mismatch and throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Dylan, per my test if you set the variable as integer, it only accepts numbers column. Have a check on your Parent ID column type and the advanced settings of your trigger, make sure you are using a correct view including the parent ID column.